# Custom Route Not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Thought I understood custom routes, but apparently not since it's not working.

Currently have this set up in `Forecast` model:

```
class Forecast < ApplicationRecord

  def get_weather_data_paris
    ForecastIO.forecast(48.8566, 2.3522) 
  end

end
```

It works for `ForecastsController` show action ..., i.e., this:

```
def show       
  @weather = @forecast.get_weather_data_paris     
  @current_weather = @weather.currently  
  @daily_weather = @weather.daily.data.first(5)
end
```

Decided that I wanted to set up a separate page for different locations, so, copied the stuff from `def show` method to `def show_paris` method:

```
def show_paris 
  @weather = @forecast.get_weather_data_paris     
  @current_weather = @weather.currently  
  @daily_weather = @weather.daily.data.first(5)
end
```

Added the action to the routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :forecasts
  root to: 'paris', to: "forecasts#show_paris"
end
```

Now, when I visit the home page, I get this error:

```
NoMethodError in ForecastsController#show_paris`
undefined method 'get_weather_data_paris' for nil:NilClass`
```

Why is this happening? What am I missing?

If it helps, here is the entire `ForecastsController`

```
class ForecastsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_forecast, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /forecasts
  # GET /forecasts.json
  def index
    @forecasts = Forecast.all
  end

  def show       
    @weather = @forecast.get_weather_data_paris     
    @current_weather = @weather.currently  
    @daily_weather = @weather.daily.data.first(5)
  end

  def show_paris 
    @weather = @forecast.get_weather_data_paris     
    @current_weather = @weather.currently  
    @daily_weather = @weather.daily.data.first(5)
  end

  # GET /forecasts/new
  def new
    @forecast = Forecast.new
  end

  # GET /forecasts/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /forecasts
  # POST /forecasts.json
  def create
    @forecast = Forecast.new(forecast_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @forecast.save
        format.html { redirect_to @forecast, notice: 'Forecast was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @forecast }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @forecast.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /forecasts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /forecasts/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @forecast.update(forecast_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @forecast, notice: 'Forecast was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @forecast }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @forecast.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /forecasts/1
  # DELETE /forecasts/1.json
  def destroy
    @forecast.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to forecasts_url, notice: 'Forecast was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_forecast
      @forecast = Forecast.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def forecast_params
      params.require(:forecast).permit(:lat, :lng)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try defining the content of your `forecasts#show_paris` method as:

```
def show_paris 
  @forecast = Forecast.find(params[:id])

  @weather = @forecast.get_weather_data_paris     
  @current_weather = @weather.currently  
  @daily_weather = @weather.daily.data.first(5)
end
```

And then in your `routes.rb`:

```
root to: 'paris', to: 'forecasts#show_paris', id: 1
```

This way you're passing an `id` in order that your `@forecast` variable isn't `nil`.

Comment: thank you for your answer! It was driving me batty! Would you by any chance know anything about Rails low-level caching?

Comment: I would recommend setting default params in the controller: `params[:id] ?
 Forecast.find(params[:id]) : Forecast.first`

Comment: @llya, do you mean like this: `@forecast = params[:id] ? Forecast.find(params[:id]) : Forecast.first`

Comment: @llya, also, I'm setting it up for for several different places so ... perhaps not the best idea to have `Forecast.first`?

Comment: @user273072545345 the idea is to get something in order to avoid the undefined method for nil error, so, depending on what you want to do, you can set it up as you prefer, the first Forecast or any other value.